# regex how to repalce redundant html tags with content into one tag

Tags: python, html, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression in Python that removes html tag duplicates.

I tried to do this with groups, but I failed:

Regex:

```
<strong>(.*)<\/strong><strong>(.*)<\/strong>
```

Python code:

```
description = re.sub(r"<strong>(.*)<\/strong><strong>(.*)<\/strong>", r"<strong>\1\2</strong>", description, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Here's some examples:

```
IN: text1 <strong>text2 </strong><strong>text3 </strong><strong>text4,</strong> text5
OUT: text1 <strong>text2 text3 text4,</strong> text5

IN: text1 <strong>text2 </strong> HELLO <strong>text3 </strong><strong>text4,</strong> text5
OUT: text1 <strong>text2 </strong> HELLO <strong>text3 text4,</strong> text5
 
IN: <strong> hello <strong>world</strong></strong>
OUT: <strong> hello world</strong>
```

Comment: How did you fail? If you recursively replace until there are no matches left, this works for me. Post the incorrect results as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome on StackOverflow!

You can see your problem from another viewpoint: instead of capturing the content of the tags, you can keep the first opening tag and the last closing tag. Closing and opening tags in the middle can be removed this way:

```py
import re
mytext = 'text1 <strong>text2 </strong> HELLO <strong>text3 </strong><strong>text4,</strong> text5'
re.subs('<\/strong>\s*<strong>', '', mytext)
```

that will result in:

```
text1 <strong>text2 </strong> HELLO <strong>text3 text4,</strong> text5
```

Note that there's an extra `\s*` to take into account any spaces or line feeds between tags.

You can also modify your regular expression using backreferences to generalize to all HTML5 tags:

```py
merge_duplicated = re.compile(r'<\/(\w+)>\s*<\1>')
```